# Access open Excel workbook using Python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, python-module, win32com

How can I find an open Excel workbook by using the `win32com` module? I just want to read a cell in an Excel workbook which has not been not saved. Or are there any documents that I can refer to?

Comment: What is an activated excel file? And how on earth would you read data from a file that is still in memory?

Comment: @AlexP.  You can read data from an unsaved workbook that only exists in memory by using COM to talk to the running instance of Excel that created it. OP used the phrase *activated Excel file* but he actually meant *open Excel workbook* and he did warn us that his English is shaky.

Comment: Thank you so much for your understanding, and also sorry for my insufficient explanation. I'll try harder next time.

Comment: @SeungYeupLEE If the answer worked for you, please accept it.

Comment: @BoarGules This is great info to have. I'll make a note of it. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

You can do it like this

```
>>> from win32com.client import Dispatch
>>> xlApp = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
```

At this point COM will connect to the running copy of Excel, if there is one, or start up a fresh one if not. You clearly want to connect to the running version. To be sure that your Python code is talking to the same instance of Excel, hide it and unhide it a few times:

```
>>> xlApp.Visible=1
>>> xlApp.Visible=0
>>> xlApp.Visible=1
```

The instance of Excel your code is talking to should react to this. Then check if it is the workbook you want. If this is an unsaved workbook then it will generally have a name like `Book1`.

```
>>> xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Name
'Book1'
```

If this gives you an error because `xlApp.ActiveWorkbook` is `None` then your code is talking to a different instance of Excel with no workbook open.

Then, to get a value off the sheet, you of course have to know what cell you want:

```
>>> xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("I3").Value
'C.2.16'
```

Your range and value will of course be different.

This is all described very clearly in Chapter 9 of Hammond & Robinson: *Python programming on Win32*, O'Reilly, 2000, ISBN 1-56592-621-8.